# send Boolean as pathvariable to controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible and a good practice to send Boolean as pathvariable to controller in url? I am using spring 3.1 and been trying to send a boolean from Jsp to the controller as @Pathvariable("yesorNo") boolean yesOrNo. But keep getting error as the request is syntactically incorrect. Any insight?

Comment: What does your request look like? Also what does the error say exactly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can, it would look like

```
@RequestMapping(value="value/{someVal}")
public void handleBooleanParameter(@PathVariable("someVal")boolean someVal){
   //do something
}
```

You would then access it with

```
http://<base url>/value/true
```

or

```
http://<base url>/value/false
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, This seems like there is no difference in sending either boolean or any other datat type (int, string..) in the url. For some reason, i was suggested to pass the boolean in @Requestparam from the form and access in the controller class.